# Loosely searching multiple words in a sentence using python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying to search words in a string but my output is false because "men" and "shirt" does not match in the string because of plural factor. What i am really looking for is to match "**men**" with "**mens**" and "**shirt**" with "**shirts**". How can I do that and if there is a easy way to accomplish this in python then please share.

```
strings = ['get-upto-70-off-on-mens-t-shirts']
words = ['men','shirt']
print map(lambda x: all(map(lambda y:y in x.split(),words)),strings)
```

**Output**

```
False
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could to one of two things: [stem](http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html) the word and check if it is in the candidate phrase, or compute [a distance measure](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html#module-nltk.metrics.distance) between the word and the candidate phrase, and accept it as a match if it is below some threshold.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is using Python's builtin `difflib` module. The function `get_close_matches()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches)) might need some tuning:

```
import difflib

strings = ['get-upto-70-off-on-mens-t-shirts']
words = ['men','shirt']

for w in words:
    for s in strings:
        s = s.split('-')
        m = difflib.get_close_matches(w, s)
        print('Word: "{}" Close matches: {}'.format(w, m))
```

Prints:

```
Word: "men" Close matches: ['mens']
Word: "shirt" Close matches: ['shirts']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use lemmatization in `NTLK` library (remove 's' 'ing' etc) or Fuzzy String Match using `FUZZYWUZZY` library.